# MVC3 Razor Stylesheet inside area

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using  mvc3 with razor. I have a normal website structure with an area for a small backend. In that area I wan't a folder with my "content" (stylesheets, js) that is only used by my backend.

WHat is the right way to reference this in my layout page of my backend?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Does this mean you want to prevent front end users from accessing 'contents' in the admin content folder? Is this meant to be a security restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the fact that an Area in MVC isn't really a physical folder-structure like it would seem in the URL (or your project). I would simply organize it something like this:

```
/Content/Public/Css
/Content/Public/Images
/Scripts/Public/
```

and

```
/Content/BackEnd/Css
/Content/BackEnd/Images
/Scripts/BackEnd
```

**UPDATE**
To clarify what I mean that Area isn't a physical folder-structure:

If you have the Area Admin in your project, The Default RouteURL is /Admin/{controller}/{action}, not /Areas/Admin/{controller}/{action} (though you're free to setup your routes like that, of course)

This means that if you add a Content-folder under your /Areas/Admin folder, and place your CSS-file within that - Visual Studio wont interpret that correctly if you simply drag and drop the file into your markup. The HTML will be generated as:

```
<link href="../../Areas/Admin/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

whereas the Url to the Admin-area is simply www.mysite.com/Admin/

This causes a bit of confusion as to what is the correct url to the Stylesheet?

`www.mysite.com/Admin/Content/stylesheet1.css` or

```
www.mysite.com/Areas/Admin/Content/stylesheet1.css
```

?

Just a matter of opinion, but that's mine anyway :)

Comment: I can assure you my Area is a physical folder structure (called Areas/ ...)

Comment: Yes, I know they are, but I don't think of folders in the same way in an MVC App as I do in for instance a webforms app. My point is you reduce the folderpath-lengths (i.e. /Areas/Admin/Content/Css/site.css).. I see no problem in keeping all the site CSS and other content in the Content-folder on the root.. No need for multiple Content-folders :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Altough I for my cms I need alot of jquery plugins and code (ckfinder etc). I would find it cleaner to put it in my backend area and the write a kind of url rule to have clean links

Comment: In your example, the css file would be
www.mysite.com/Areas/Admin/Content/stylesheet1.css
Note that physical location of the file trump the routing rules.